# remove duplicate lines after first word in sentace linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, comparison, duplicate

I was looking to remove duplicates of lines of text but after a space from the first word in this format;

```
apples blue
apples green
apples are sometimes red
pairs green
pairs black
potato brown
lemon
...
```

Anything after a space on each line would get disregarded, then removed duplicates.

Would end up with;

```
apples
pairs
potato
lemon
```

I was hopefully looking for a way this could be done in linux terminal like;

```
command file_in.txt single_sout.txt
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-liner:

```
cut -d " " -f 1 file_in.txt | uniq > file_out.txt
```

First you use the `cut` command with the delimiter `-d " "`, and then get the first field with `-f 1` from the file `file_in.txt`. Then pipe the result into the `uniq` command, and that will remove duplicates from the list. Finally you redirect the result to `file_out.txt`.

Comment: will this work on large files gb's in size?, thanks for the reply also

Comment: For very large files it might be worth doing in 2 steps, so `cut -d " " -f 1 file_in.txt > file_tmp.txt` and then `uniq file_tmp.txt > file_out.txt`. That will help narrow down the issue if something fails. I don't know of any file size restrictions for either `cut` or `uniq`, so the only real way to find out would be to test it. Running the commands is non-destructive though, so giving it a shot won't hurt.